Can change occur without time?
I have heard of the notion of temporal vacuums, that is, periods of time where nothing changes. But what about the obverse case? What I mean is, can there be change without time? I am asking because, at least according to my understanding, some theories of physics say that a spaceless and timeless "quantum vacuum" gave rise to our universe. In other words, in those theories, a change occurred without the notion of time. But perhaps I am just misunderstanding those physics theories. In any case, I want to know, have any philosophers, specifically philosophers of physics, written about this topic of change without time? I would like to see such texts.

It’s been reported that there’s some instant Eureka type of knowledge such that at that instant click some proposition is changed from the state of unknown to known, at least for some people’s accessibility to it within the vast amount of possible worlds …

@DoubleKnot Which newspaper was that in?

^Granted, I don't think the answers there are particularly high-quality, but it does seem like a pretty close dupe.

@8Mad0Manc8 iirc there was just a recent post in this site about this report, of course that may not fit for OP's request...

@DoubleKnot With no disrespect. Which newspaper was that in again?   If your going to cite references in posts be more clear with a citation. I post lots of comments but omit references if it's just my opinion.

No, a change can't occur without the passage of time.  The best model of the universe is a gas of point particles.  If even one particle moves relative to the rest, that's a different moment in time.  The smallest amount of time is between two consecutive moments in time, represented by ∆t.  Any larger amount of time can be represented by n×∆t, where n represents a natural number.
Think of things this way, if time passes even though nothing moved relative to anything else, at the first moment in time, a billion years could have passed before the second moment in time occurred, or a trillion years, or etc., which leads to an indefinite amount of time between any two moments in time, which is physically untenable.  The only way to make sense when discussing time, is to use moments in time, and a smallest amount of time equal to a  unit.  This spells the end of the theory of special relativity, which abolishes the notion of the current moment in time.

No the passage of time is relative to a  factor of the time recorded between the two events and the relative time of the first event to its absolute self how do you measure time. Its only via an experience of time that is determined by processes in your mind.

Quantum state transitions are often described as instantaneous. I don't remember enough quantum physics to know if that is accurate or not. I'm also not sure whether that addresses your actual question.

Do you mean the so called "collapse of the wave function"?

So your question is, is there any latent energy in a transition of states. As far as I know that's the bohr model of atomic nature.

I mean that an excited atom which emits a photon and drops to a less excited state does not appear to have any intermediate states. I do not reliably remember whether this would be expressed as being in an indeterminate state for some amount of time, or if the transition can simply be said to have occurred with no transition time associated with it.
